# How can I test $H_0:\sigma^2_1=\sigma^2_2$?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, mean

I have a few hundred estimates of a parameter calculated from two different models and I would like to know if these parameters have different variances.

What is a straightforward test for comparing the variances of these parameters? (straightforward meaning, least assumptions).

Comment: Are you comparing *variances* (as asserted in the first line) or *means* (as indicated in the third line)?

Comment: @whuber I had confused myself; I have clarified my question.

Comment: @Abe It seems now you have reversed "means" and "variances" but there's still a contradiction!  (Unless perhaps you want to compare the variances of the means.)  What do you mean by "variable": the means or the underlying values on which they are based?

Comment: @whuber sorry, is that better?

Comment: @Abe The new title helps a lot.  But just to be clear: are the sigma-squareds the variances of the *means* or of the underlying *variables* upon which the means are based?

Comment: @whuber the underlying variables; I have removed the term 'mean' for clarity.

Comment: Anwsers (including mine :) )  to that question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/841/comparing-the-variance-of-paired-observations/7013#7013 might help.

Comment: [This paper][1] gives a method you could use to test if variances are different. [1]:http://bayes.wustl.edu/glb/diff.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For comparing *variances*, Wilcox suggests a percentile bootstrap method. See [chapter 5.5.1 of 'Introduction to Robust Estimation and Hypothesis Testing'](http://books.google.com/books?id=_tAJr4ooOM8C&lpg=PR1&dq=Introduction%20to%20Robust%20Estimation%20and%20Hypothesis%20Testing&pg=PA170#v=onepage&q&f=false). This is available as `comvar2` from [the wrs package](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=468) in R.

**edit**: to find the amount of bootstrap differences to trim from each side for different values of $\alpha$, one would perform a Monte Carlo study, as suggested by Wilcox. I have a quick and dirty one here in Matlab (duck from thrown shoes):

```
randn('state',0);           %to make the results replicable.
alphas = [0.001,0.005,0.01,0.025,0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20,0.25,0.333];
nreps  = 4096;
nsizes = round(2.^ (4:0.5:9));
nboots = 599;
cutls  = nan(numel(nsizes),numel(alphas));

for ii=1:numel(nsizes)
    n = nsizes(ii);
    imbalance = nan(nreps,1);
    for jj=1:nreps
        x1 = randn(n,1);x2 = randn(n,1);
        %make bootstrap samples;
        x1b = x1(ceil(n * rand(n,nboots)));
        x2b = x2(ceil(n * rand(n,nboots)));
        %compute stdevs
        sig1 = std(x1b,1);sig2 = std(x2b,1);
        %compute difference in stdevs
        Dvar = (sig1.^2 - sig2.^2);
        %compute the minimum of {the # < 0} and {the # > 0}
        %in (1-alpha) of the cases you want this minimum to match
        %your l number; then let u = 599 - l + 1
        imbalance(jj,1) = min(sum(Dvar < 0),sum(Dvar > 0));
    end
    imbalance = sort(imbalance);
    cutls(ii,:) = interp1(linspace(0,1,numel(imbalance)),imbalance(:)',alphas,'nearest');
end
%plot them;
lh = loglog(nsizes(:),cutls + 1);
legend(lh,arrayfun(@(x)(sprintf('alpha = %g',x)),alphas,'UniformOutput',false))
ylabel('l + 1');
xlabel('sample size, n_m');
```

I get the rather unhelpful plot:
[image]

A little bit of hackery indicates that a model of the form $l + 0.5 = \exp{5.18} \alpha^{0.94} n^{0.067}$ fits my Monte Carlo simulations fairly well, but they do not give the same results that Wilcox quotes in his book. You might be better served running these experiments yourself at your preferred $\alpha$.

**edit** I ran this experiment again, using many more replicates ($2^{18}$) per sample size. Here's a table of the empirical values of $l$. The first row is a NaN, then the alpha (type I rate). Following that, the first column is the size of the samples, $n$, then the empirical values of $l$. (I would expect that as $n \to \infty$ we would have $l \to 599 \alpha /2$)

```
NaN,0.001,0.005,0.01,0.025,0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25,0.333
16,0,0,1,4,9,22,35,49,64,88
23,0,0,1,4,10,23,37,51,66,91
32,0,0,1,4,10,24,38,52,67,92
45,0,0,1,5,11,25,39,54,69,94
64,0,0,2,5,12,26,41,55,70,95
91,0,1,2,6,13,27,42,56,71,96
128,0,1,2,6,13,28,42,58,72,97
181,0,1,2,6,13,28,43,58,73,98
256,0,1,2,6,14,28,43,58,73,98
362,0,1,2,7,14,29,44,59,74,99
512,0,1,2,7,14,29,44,59,74,99
```

Comment: @shabbychef thanks for pointing me in this direction. It only took me about 5 min to download, read the section chapter, and compute; very much appreciated, but I am going to hold of on accepting your answer in hopes that other methods will be suggested - as this one is rather limited (only tests at alpha = 0.05, and there may be other options for large samples as in the present case)

Comment: @shabbychef I've already +1 but was very unlucky with the R package -- OS X build doesn't include the aforementioned function :(

Comment: @chl AFAIK the package is just a convenient bundle for the functions that are available at http://www-rcf.usc.edu/~rwilcox/Rallfun-v13

Comment: @Abe: for values of $\alpha \ne 0.05$, Wilcox outlines the method for constructing the cutoff values of $l$ and $u$, but I agree it would be nice if they were available as rough functions of $\alpha$.

Comment: @shabbychef I am confused - in the book it says 'the method can be applied only with $\alpha=0.05$, modifications based on other $\alpha$ values have not been derived"? His 2002 paper abstract hints otherwise, but I am not able to access it.

Comment: 'The method just described is based on a strategy similar to Gosset's derivation of Student's t: Assume normality and then make adjustments so that for small sample sizes, accurate probability coverage is obtained.'

Comment: @caracal Thanks. I guess the Win/Linux versions available on RForge are more up to date.

Comment: I had thought there were 3 or 4 tried and true methods, such as Levene's, for testing the difference between variances. Why would one want to turn to these intricate and improvised approaches?