# Determining the relationship between salesperson and products sold?

Tags: correlation, variance

#### Context:

I have a series of figures for car sales that show me (a) the usual number of car sales for particular models and (b) the number of car sales by a particular car salesperson for each model.

Let's say the values are:

```
Model | Sales by all Salespeople | Sales by Salesperson x
    A |                      100 |                     20
    B |                       50 |                     40
    C |                       50 |                      0
```

I want to find out if Salesperson x is significantly more responsible for sales of a particular model.

My first thought is to determine the rate of sales per model vs the rate of sales per model for the salesperson, i.e.:

```
Model | % Total Sales for all Salespeople | % Total Sales for Salesperson x
    A |                               50% |                             33%
    B |                               25% |                             66%
    C |                               25% |                              0%
```

However, naturally every salesperson has a significant variation in the cars they sell.

#### Question:

- How do I determine if salesperson variation from the mean is statistically significant?

#### Initial Thoughts:

I *think* the Pearson correlation has some bearing, as perhaps may chi-square distribution, but I really don't have the background yet to understand why, so introductory help is appreciated.

Comment: perhaps a duplicate of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8586/how-can-i-test-h-0-sigma2-1-sigma2-2

Comment: @David - cheers for the link

Answer (score 1):

Chi square test, but I'd set it up as follows:

Model  |  this salesman  |  all other salesmen

A       |       20      |        80

B       |       40       |       10

etc.

Chi square test of independence, with expected values equal to row total * column total / grand total.

Null hypothesis: this salesman = same as all other.

Most stat books will have this test.